# Python BeautifulSoup (need Guidance not answer only)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas
import bs4
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

data_df = pandas.read_csv("tickers.csv")

print(data_df.columns[0])

req = Request("http://performance.morningstar.com/perform/Performance/stock/annual-dividends.action?&t=XSES:D05&region=sgp&culture=en-US&cur=&ops=clear&ndec=2&y=5", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, "lxml")

table = soup.find("th", {"class": "row_lbl"})

print(table.nextSibling.text)
```

if i did print(table.text), my output is "Dividend Amount" which is correct.

can anyone explain why does .nextSibling is not working here? i need explanation and not a straight out answer, i am new to python & coding and i want to learn.

the error for .nextSibling.text is below

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the tr element from you url:

```
<tr> 
                <th class="row_lbl">Dividend Amount</th>
                <td align="right">0.56</td>
                <td align="right">0.56</td>
                <td align="right">0.58</td>
                <td align="right">0.60</td>
                <td align="right">0.60</td>
            </tr>
```

Now here the "th" element with class : row_lbl i.e  table =

```
<th class="row_lbl">Dividend Amount</th>
```

so table.text should return "Dividend Amount"

In BeautifulSoup, the elements not only include tags but also text/whitespaces between them, which BeautifulSoup marks as NavigableString.

In your case there are whitespaces/line breaks between the "td" tags. These are also treated as elements(Navigable string) which obviously do not have the properties of html elements.

So if your html was something like below, there would be no navigable Strings:

```
 <th class="row_lbl">Dividend Amount</th><td align="right">0.56</td><td align="right">0.56</td><td align="right">0.58</td><td align="right">0.60</td><td align="right">0.60</td>
```

To Skip the navigable strings in current case:. Try:

```
while True:
        table= table.nextSibling
        if table==None:
            break
        print table   # you will see that this printing whitespaces sometimes
        try:
            tag_name = table.name
        except AttributeError:
            tag_name = ""
        if tag_name == "td":
            print table.text
```

Comment: i am getting error for table.nextSibling.text. the error is.

  File "grab_dividend.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(table.nextSibling.text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 730, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: i am not sure if this post has been flagged as answered because Mithilesh Kumar reply has "Answered" status. i still need help though. thank you

Comment: thanks Kumar, it worked.

can you explain what you meant by there is text inside them? i cant see any text when i inspect the HTML.

Comment: updated the answer. Let me know if something is not clear

Comment: thank you for your kind guidance and teaching. appreciated it. i have fully understood about the technical terms and methods now.